# setTimeout Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation` is thrown when calling `setTimeout` with a variable callback. I read that this happens when `this` refers to another object in the callback and that `bind` or arrow functions are used to solve this. However, no `this` in my callback.

The code is as follows:

```js
class AlarmService {

    constructor(callback) {
        this._alarms = {};
        this.setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
        this.clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
        this._callback = callback || function () {};
    }

    create(alarmName, when, title, message) {
        this._alarms[alarmName] = {
            'title': title,
            'message': message
        };
        this._alarms.timeout = this.setTimeout(this._callback, when - Date.now(),
                               this._alarms[alarmName]);
    }
}

let alarms = new AlarmService(function (alarm) {
    console.log('Alarm', alarm.name);
});

// Exception is thrown here
alarms.create('alarmName', Date.now() + 3000, 'Title', 'Message');
```

Note that I use babel and es2015.

Comment: The function is throwing the error because you've copied a reference to it to your own object, and then you are invoking it with your own object as the `this` context. It makes no difference that the callback does not refer to `this`. The problem is that you're calling `this.setTimeout()` instead of `window.setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sample code, functions setTimeout and clearTimeout are being invoked with an invalid context (`this`). On possible fix is binding to the correct context (`window`):

```
constructor(callback) {
    this._alarms = {};
    this.setTimeout = window.setTimeout.bind(window);
    this.clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout.bind(window);
    this._callback = callback || function () {};
}
```

It is usual to think of the `this` object inside a function pointing to the object to the left of the dot in the invocation:

```
alerts.create(...) // inside create(), this === alerts
   ^
   |___ "this"
```

When there's no dot, it depends whether the caller function is strict:

```
var create = alerts.create
create() // this === Window or global
^
|_____ no dot
```

And

```
'use strict'
var create = alerts.create
create() // this === undefined
^
|_____ no dot
```

Given we call `setTimeout` without a dot, we may think that the `this` context doesn't matter. But in browsers it will complain if you call it with a dot, or use a variant that pass as context something different than window.

Firefox:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Chrome:

> TypeError: 'setTimeout' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.

---

Others suggested sticking to the usual `setTimeout(fn, timeout)`.
Yet another way is creating an anonymous function:

```
this.setTimeout = (fn, timeout) => setTimeout(fn, timeout);
```

Comment: or use setTimeout and clearTimeout, without this antipatternish code

Answer (score 1):

There is no `this` in your callback, however `setTimeout` is called globally.
So `this.setTimeout` should be `setTimeout`

```js
class AlarmService {

    constructor(callback) {
        this._alarms = {};
        this.setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
        this.clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
        this._callback = callback || function () {};
    }

    create(alarmName, when, title, message) {
        this._alarms[alarmName] = {
            'title': title,
            'message': message
        };
        this._alarms.timeout = setTimeout(this._callback, when - Date.now(), this._alarms[alarmName]);
    }
}

let alarms = new AlarmService(function (alarm) {
    console.log('Alarm', alarm);
});

alarms.create('alarmName', Date.now() + 3000, 'Title', 'Message'); // Exception is thrown here
```

I also changed your log line because your alarm does not have a name.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I passed the `wanted context` to `setTimeout` instead of `its callback`

this the wrong code, where I pass `this` to `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout.call(this, function () {
    // this.model.starIcon = "fa-star";
    this._toggleStarIcon()
}, 150);
```

I correct way to pass you context is to pass it to `setTimeout callback`

I used [`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to do that

here is the correct code

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
    // this.model.starIcon = "fa-star";
    this._toggleStarIcon()
}, this), 150);
```

hope this helps you